# iOS:OCMapper: Deserialize date from json

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, json

I have integrated OCMapper for converting json string to custom model object.I cannot able to deserialize date object. for example I have one json like

```
NSString* sampleOutput=@"{\"UserType\":\"Admin\",\"testdate\":\"/Date(1438545600000+0400)/\"}";

NSData* sampleDate= [sampleOutput dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *loginDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:sampleDate options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&responseError];

MyModel* loginResponse= [[ObjectMapper sharedInstance] objectFromSource:loginDictionary toInstanceOfClass:[MyModel class]];
```

My Model class structure is

```
`@interface MyModel : NSObject
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString* userType;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSDate* testdate;
@end`
```

But I got nil value for testdate object. Kindly provide me best way to do so.

If the json is

```
 NSString* sampleOutput=@"{\"UserType\":\"Admin\",\"testdate\":\"2015-08-05\"}";
```

I can able to parse the date by `InCodeMappingProvider`

like

```
InCodeMappingProvider *inCodeMappingProvider = [[InCodeMappingProvider alloc] init];
        NSDateFormatter *dateOfBirthFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateOfBirthFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-dd-MM"];
        [inCodeMappingProvider setDateFormatter:dateOfBirthFormatter forPropertyKey:@"testdate" andClass:[MyModel class]];
        [[ObjectMapper sharedInstance] setMappingProvider:inCodeMappingProvider];
```

But I need to convert the specific C# Date serialize format `NSString* sampleOutput=@"{\"UserType\":\"Admin\",\"testdate\":\"/Date(1438545600000+0400)/`

Comment: I am using C# Rest WebService where the date objects are serialized as /Date(23123123+0400)/

Comment: What do you mean you get nil for testate? There is no parsing in your sample. `testDate` is currently a `NSString` with a another format. "Date(timeStampLikeUnixWithMaybeMilliSecondsFollowedByTimeZone)". I don't know if you OCMapper can translate it without doing some modifications.

Comment: @Larme MyModel* loginResponse= [[ObjectMapper sharedInstance] objectFromSource:loginDictionary toInstanceOfClass:[MyModel class]];

Comment: above code is for parsing the dictionary to object. In debugger I can able to see nil value for loginResponse.testdate

Comment: And also testdate is NSDate type not NSString.

Comment: If you replace `@property(nonatomic,strong) NSDate* testdate;` with `@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString* testdate;` does it works? I read quickly the main page of OCMapper on GitHub, and it seems that the only way is to use Custom Transforms, because the date format you use is custom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found answer.

In ObjectMapper.m-> processDictionary:

```
// Convert NSString to NSDate if needed
                    if ([propertyTypeString isEqualToString:@"NSDate"])
                    {
                        if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]])
                        {
                            nestedObject = value;
                        }
                        else if ([value hasPrefix:@"/Date("]){
                            nestedObject = [self myCustomDateConversion:value];
                        }
                        else if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
                        {
                            nestedObject = [self dateFromString:value forProperty:propertyName andClass:class];
                        }
                    }
```